# Update AVMutableVideoComposition on AVPlayerItem faster than video framerate

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to preview a `CIFilter` applied to a video using `AVMutableVideoComposition`'s `applyingCIFiltersWithHandler` initializer.

I have several sliders that change values in the filter, which get reflected by the `AVPlayer`. The only issue is that there is a noticeable lag between moving the slider and the next frame of the video applying my change.

If I use a higher framerate video, the applier block is called more often and the lag is not noticeable.

I've tried recreating and replacing the `AVMutableVideoComposition` on the current `AVPlayerItem` whenever the slider moves but this looks jerky while the video is playing. (It works very well if the video is paused. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1966/_index.html)

Any idea how to do this without writing a custom video player that has a way to invalidate the frame?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a decent solution I managed to find.

I noticed that putting a sleep in the frame processing block actually seemed to *improve* the perceived performance.

The `AVMutableVideoComposition` must build up a buffer of frames and the delay I'm seeing is that buffer running out before the frames with new filter values show up. Sleeping in the frame processing block prevented the buffer from filling up making the changes show up immediately.

I looked through the documentation of `AVMutableVideoComposition` for the millionth time and found this little gem in the docs for `sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming`.

> If an empty edit is encountered in the source asset’s track, the compositor composes frames as needed up to the frequency specified in frameDuration property. Otherwise the frame timing for the video composition is derived from the source asset's track with the corresponding ID.

I had previously tried setting the `frameDuration` on the composition but couldn't get it to go faster than the video's framerate. If I set the sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming to `kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid` it actually lets me speed up the framerate.

By setting the framerate to be extremely high (1000 fps), the phone can never fill up the buffer, making the changes appear immediate.

```
composition.sourceTrackIDForFrameTiming = kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid

let frameRateTooHighForPhone = CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 1000)
composition.frameDuration = frameRateTooHighForPhone
```

It's a little bit hackier than is ideal, but it's not a bad solution.

Comment: This also works for reducing the frame duration as well. Nice find!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for posting this, Randall.  The above frameDuration hack fixed the lag I was seeing when enabling/disabling layers; so, it seems I'm moving in the right direction.

The issue I now need to figure out is why using this frameDuration hack also seems to have a side effect of introducing glitching and processing hangs in the video processing.  Sometimes it works great, but usually the video freezes after a few seconds while the audio track continues to play.  Without the hack, playback is solid but changes to composition lag.  With the hack, changes are seemingly instantaneous and the video playback has about a 10% chance of being solid - otherwise, hangs.  (If I scrub around enough it seems to somehow fix itself, and when it does the universe feels like a better place.)

I'm very new to working with AVMutableVideoComposition and the AVVideoCompositing protocol, and documentation concerning my usage seems to be sparse, so I'm posting this reply in case anyone has any more golden nuggets of info to share with me.

Comment: Hopefully you already found a solution by now but was this a problem on the device or simulator? I had similar issues on the simulator but it works fine on the device.